# ffmpeg can not be able to convert ivr file to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, ivr

I want to convert ivr file to mp4 using ffmpeg, but it seems ffmpeg can not be able to convert ivr file,

when i try to convert ivr file to mp4, getting below error

"Invalid data found when processing input"

how can achieve same?

Thanks,
Vishal Parekh

Comment: What audio file format is the IVR using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many free voice file conversion programs on the Internet.  I would suggest first trying to convert your "IVR" file to MP3 or WAV, and then try converting that to MP4.  Your program may not be able to convert directly from the IVR format to MP4.